Movie about survival and cannibalism set in a winter forest in the past
I'm looking for a film that from what I remember was "maybe" set during the American Civil War.
A bunch of deserters are being kept at a prison camp doing labour work. They're deep in the mountainous forest during winter, there is snow everywhere.
A group decide to escape and they do into the surrounding forest. As they get deeper and deeper into the forest they become desperately hungry and decide to kill one of the group for food.
IMPORTANT: The most memorable thing that I can remember about the movie is a death scene, one of the group grabs a big rock and throws it on his sleeping companion, it doesn't kill him but he's twitching violently, it was brutal. They hang him up by the legs after slitting his throat to let the blood drain out.

Sounds like Van Diemen's Land (2009)
From Wikipedia:

A group of transported convicts, suffering brutal treatment at the Sarah Island penal settlement on Van Diemens Land, escape into the Tasmanian wilderness in hopes of reaching the settlements to the east. Their enthusiasm and bravado soon give way to hunger, which saps their strength and causes them to despair. Former urban dwellers, the English, Irish and Scottish convicts realise that not only are they lost, but they do not even know how to hunt or fish. The oppressive nature of landscape becomes the setting for murder, as hunger forces the group to turn to cannibalism, killing and eating the members of the group one by one. The men do all in their power to keep moving, watch their back and avoid sleep, lest they be the next meal.

Hanging scene
Trailer
Another version The Last Confession of Alexander Pearce (2008)

Could it be Ravenous?

Captain John Boyd receives a promotion after defeating the enemy command in a battle of the Mexican-American War, but because the general realizes it was an act of cowardice that got him there, he is given a backhanded promotion to Fort Spencer, where he is third in command. The others at the fort are two Indians, George and his sister, Martha, who came with the place, Chaplain Toffler, Reich, the soldier; Cleaves, a drugged-up cook; and Knox, who is frequently drunk. When a Scottish stranger named Colquhoun appears and recovers from frostbite almost instantly after being bathed, he tells a story about his party leader, Ives, eating members of the party to survive. As part of their duty, they must go up to the cave where this occurred to see if any have survived. Only Martha, Knox, and Cleaves stay behind. George warns that since Colquhoun admits to eating human flesh, he must be a Windigo, a ravenous cannibalistic creature.

I haven't seen it in ages so I don't recall specific scenes, but it seems to match the basic storyline.

That isn't the movie, thank you for answering though.
